substitute for "from" keyword in css for firefox
i used lines similar to these in my css: 
--primary4: hsl(from var(--prim-200) h 50% l);
--tr-primary3: rgb(from var(--prim-300) r g b / 0.2);
i have found that they dont work in firefox and instead display as just transparent
and i couldnt find any workaround to display the exact color on the internet
for additional information these are the other variables in the css:
--primary-light: 344, 70%;
--prim-200: hsl(var(--primary-light), 80%);
--prim-300: hsl(var(--primary-light), 70%);
all methods i tried to solve it involved not using a variable color like i do and instead splitting it or otherwise

CCS Color Module 5 is still a working draft and Firefox, like Safari, has only partial support.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/ for links to the test suite.  Chrome has only had support for a few months.  The Chrome developer page announcing support (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/css-relative-color-syntax) has a "before" section to show the previous syntax.
